# Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: c#, .net

The error occurs on one of the forms, I can edit the form and click the update button when I first go to the page and everything works fine, but if I visit the page and wait for about 2 -5 minutes and then try editing the form and clicking the update button I ge this error;

It looks to be something wrong with the session ID and I thought it could be something to do with timeout issues but im not sure.

Any suggestions will be appreciated:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error
>   and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 80: protected void
>   imgUpdateDetails_Click(object sender,
>   EventArgs e)
>   Line 81: {
>   Line 82:    SessionManager.CurrentBusinessClubMember.BCMListingDetails.BusinessClubMemberID = SessionManager.CurrentBusinessClubMember.ID;
>   Line 83:
>   SessionManager.CurrentBusinessClubMember.BCMListingDetails.Address1 = editaddressline1.Value;
>   Line 84:
>   SessionManager.CurrentBusinessClubMember.BCMListingDetails.Address2 = editaddressline2.Value;
>
> Source File:
>   d:Sitesdemelzabusinessclub.co.ukpublic_htmlWebsiteListingDetails.aspx.cs Line: 82
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>   DemelzaBusinessClubSite_ListingDetails.imgUpdateDetails_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   d:Sitesdemelzabusin/essclub.co.ukpublic_htmlWebsiteListingDetails.aspx.cs:82
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +79
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +175
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:2.0.50727.5444;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5420

Comment: Debug your code and look at the value of the session id. Also if you can avoid using Session please do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your method

```
imgUpdateDetails_Click
```

you have a line that states

```
SessionManager.CurrentBusinessClubMember.BCMListingDetails.Address2 = editaddressline2.Value;
```

The error indicates that one of the following hasn't been instantiated before being used.

```
SessionManager
SessionManager.CurrentBusinessClubMember
SessionManager.CurrentBusinessClubMember.BCMListingDetails
editaddressline2
```

unless you are storing these objects somewhere like in the session and pulling them out on each post back they will be null!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like gDetails is null from your stack trace, and/or SessionManager or SessionManager.CurrentBusinessClubMember.

The / Application just means your application is running in the root directory of your server.

Answer (score 0):

Something on line 82 is `null`, i.e. it hasn't been set to a value.
Try placing a breakpoint on line 82 and debugging the application. Then inspect each object to see what is null.